# About the meaning of associated graded ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, graded-rings

Let $G$ be any multiplicative group (abelian or not). Suppose that $R$ is a $G$-graded ring, i.e., there exists a family of additive subgroup $\{R_g\}_{g\in G}$ such that $R=\bigoplus_{g\in G}R_g$ and, for all $g,h\in G$, $R_gR_h\subseteq R_{gh}$.

**My question**:

If $I\subseteq R$ is an ideal (not necessarily graded), what means that $I_{\textrm{gr}}$ is the ***associated graded ideal of*** $I$?

Someone could help me with this, please? Thanks.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Could be the ideal generated by all homogeneous elements in $I$.

Comment: I suspect the author means that you treat $R$ as being $G$-filtered (this works when $G$ is ordered); then $I$ becomes a $G$-filtered module as well, and thus has an associated graded module.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Your guess looks more complicated than necessary. Usually there are two homogeneous ideals associated to an ideal in a graded ring: the one I've mentioned before and its homogenization. I can't guess to which one of them the OP refers to.

Comment: I would like to say where did my question come from. I was reading the article "Group-graded rings, smash products, and group actions. COHEN & MONTGOMERY" and there, in the page 252, the authors say, on a Lemma, about $N_{\textrm{gr}}(R)$ and $N(R)_{\textrm{gr}}$. Where $N(R)_{\textrm{gr}}$ is the graded  prime radical associated at the prime radical $N(R)$. Of course, $R$ is a ring. Again, sorry for my english and thanks for listening.